# Exclude an id from update

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

Can I exclude a specific id from `update=":myComponent"`?

I have a larger page (with several tables, input fields and so on) which is wrapped in a `<p:panel id="outerPanel">`. Most of the time, I just execute `update=":outerPanel"`, which works quite fine. But now I'm facing a problem that I have to update the page except for ONE table.

How can I exclude that table (or any component in general) from an update process?

Comment: Is this using Primefaces? Your "<p:panel" suggests it

Comment: Setting the disabled attribute of an input component prevents JSF from applying its values, but don't know about other components. I would rather mention specific ids and skip table's id in the `update` in order to exclude it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ID not to refresh can be identified by some logic (i.e.:

```
if(myVar==1) { idToExclue = 'id1';}
else // ... etc
```

Then you can try building a JSF call using the `jsf.util.chain`: (Note this uses Mojarra JSF impl.)

```
function myJsfSubmit(callerElement) {
  var myIdsToSubmit = 'main-form:id-to-refresh-1 main-form:id-to-refresh-2';
  // put your logic to exclude the desired ID here
  // ...
  // then
  jsf.util.chain(callerElement,null,'mojarra.ab(this,event,\'action\',
      \'main-form:id_to-submit\',\'+ myIdsToSubmit +\')');
  return false;
  }
```

And use that above function on the `onClick()` or `onSubmit()` of your form or component:

```
<h:commandButton onclick="myJsfSubmit(this)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I think that is not possible from the facelet. On the server side you could manipulate the ajax request, but I don't think that is what you want.

Maybe your view allows to wrap some `h:panelGroup` around the parts to update.